# iOS Swift - How to do 360 degree flip animation using CABasicAnimation and CATransform3DRotate with "m34" transform?

Tags: swift, perspective, cabasicanimation, catransform3drotate

Despite all my best efforts, I can't figure out how to do a full cycle rotation animation of a UIView using CATransform3DRotate from left to right. Kindly note that I can already rotate it 360 degree with CABasicAnimation, but without CATransform3DRotate. However, I want to use **.m34** transform for perspective depth. Solutions involving UIView.animate/transitions are not helpful in what I am trying to accomplish. Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:** I searched far and wide in Stackoverflow and other places, but didn't find anything that describes how to do 360 rotation with CATransform3DRotate. Calling top guns out there for help as this is a question that does not seem to have been answered before. Thanks!

**Here is the code that rotates UIView 180 degree.**

```
var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -200.0

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
animation.toValue = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat( Double.pi), 0, 1, 0)
animation.duration = 0.8
animation.beginTime = 0.0
animation.fillMode = .forwards
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
cardView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "360flip")
```

Comment: It is actually working. You can change the value to check it. Test it with 1.0 / -100.0 or less to see the effect.

Comment: @ShreeramBhat I am struggling with doing a full 360 degree rotation of the UIView. I can see the perspective depth with .m34 anywhere below -400. Thanks for your response.

Comment: What about using 2 `CABasicAnimation`s with `CAAnimationGroup`?

Comment: @Ryan Tried a couple of times already, but didn't help. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is replacing the entire transform of the animating layer, meaning you can't apply the perspective transform to it. You also have issues with the end state being mathematically identical to the beginning state, and to cope with this you're trying to chain animations together, and using fill modes, which makes the whole thing more complicated.

First, let's deal with the transform. To get the perspective you want to set the `.m34` of the layer's transform, which you're already doing:

```
var perspective = CATransform3DIdentity
perspective.m34 = 1 / -200
cardView.layer.transform = perspective
```

Next, to only touch the rotation of the layer's transform, you can use a more precise key path than `transform`:

```
let rotate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
rotate.fromValue = 0
```

This will leave the rest of the layer's transform intact.

Finally, how to force the animation engine to notice a difference when the end of the animation is identical to the start? Use `byValue`:

```
rotate.byValue = CGFloat.pi * 2
```

This forces the layer to take the long way round to 360 degrees, instead of the lazy shortcut of staying exactly where it is.

The final, complete code is:

```
var perspective = CATransform3DIdentity
perspective.m34 = 1 / -200
cardView.layer.transform = perspective
let rotate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
rotate.fromValue = 0
rotate.byValue = CGFloat.pi * 2
rotate.duration = 2
cardView.layer.add(rotate, forKey: nil)
```

Giving this result:

[image: A label rotating 360 degrees with perspective]

Comment: Very nice!  Superior to my answer (which I'm deleting).

Comment: Great answer! Simple, robust and beautifully explained. I can see flaw in my approach.